# When is it not possible to quote nil?

Tags: elisp

I've never quoted nil before, as I can't see any sense in doing that, but I just played around with some code and it seems that in most cases it is possible to quote nil without any effect. However when I use `condition-case` with a quoted nil as the first argument, I get an error `(wrong-type-argument symbolp (quote nil))`.

```
(condition-case 'nil
    (/ 2 0)
  (error "foo"))
```

Why does quoting nil cause problems when using it this way ?

Comment: Hint: `nil` is not really relevant, e.g., `(condition-case 'some-other-symbol ...)` also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever the variable in question is evaluated, `'nil` and `nil` are the same.

E.g., all functions (but not necessarily macros and special forms!) get their arguments evaluated.

If it is not evaluated, like the first argument of the special form `condition-case`, you cannot quote it because then you are passing a list `(quote nil)` instead of the symbol `nil`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I had to read a more detailed answer to understand this http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/722/11377.

Comment: @bertfred: yes, your question was marked a dupe for a reason! :-)

Comment: Without your answer I wouldn't have realized, that the macro was the reason ;)

Comment: Technically `condition-case` is not a macro, but a special-form.